# SQL search people by data in 4 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to make a search engine that finds people based on information from the `people` table and 3 other tables (`phones`, `emails`, `addresses`). The user can pick 0 to 4 search parameters (see `WHERE` clause in my sql code), if 0 parameters are chosen, the desired output is the entire database.

I could search one table at a time and remember the IDs, but that seems inefficient.

I also have this SQL that can do everything in a single query, but it doesn't work exactly as intended:

```
SELECT 
  people.id,
  name,
  group_concat(
    DISTINCT concat( number, ' (', phones.description, ')' )
    ORDER BY phones.description
    SEPARATOR '\n'
  ) AS phones,
  group_concat(
    DISTINCT concat( email, ' (', emails.description, ')' )
    ORDER BY emails.description
    SEPARATOR '\n'
  ) AS emails,
  group_concat(
    DISTINCT concat( address, ' (', addresses.description, ')' )
    ORDER BY addresses.description
    SEPARATOR '\n'
  ) AS addresses
FROM people
LEFT OUTER JOIN phones
  ON phones.person_id = people.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN emails
  ON emails.person_id = people.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN addresses
  ON addresses.person_id = people.id
WHERE
  name LIKE ?
  AND number LIKE ?
  AND email LIKE ?
  AND address LIKE ?
GROUP BY people.id
ORDER BY people.id DESC
```

The problems with this query are:

1. If I search by phone number and someone has more than one phone number, the resulting query will include only the number I searched for and not this person's other number.
2. It is extremely inefficient, iterating over the database more than necessary and returning the same entires several times (which is why I ended up using `DISTINCT` in the `group_concat(...)` function).

SQL commands to create a sample database:

```
CREATE TABLE people (
id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(120)
);

CREATE TABLE phones (
person_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
number VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
description VARCHAR(25)
);

CREATE TABLE emails (
person_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
description VARCHAR(25)
);

CREATE TABLE addresses (
person_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
address VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
description VARCHAR(25)
);
```

Comment: I'm surprised you don't get an error on the `Group By` and `Order By`, since that table does not exist. `GROUP BY person.id ORDER BY person.id DESC`

Comment: @WEI_DBA oops, that's a thing I just added for readability after testing the code, and wrote `person` instead of `people` x: now I corrected it

Comment: Figured as much... but, you don't have any Indexes, foreign keys or Primary Keys on the child tables either... Might be cause for the inefficiency.

Comment: Can the user actually pick several parameters to search by? Or is it just 1 parameter and they pick the type?

Comment: The user picks between 0 and 4 parameters (listed in the `WHERE` clause in my query)

Comment: You need to join with each of the child tables twice. Once to match the search field, and a second time to get all the rows that relate to the person who is found.

Comment: You also have to put the search terms in the `ON` clause, not `WHERE`. Otherwise, if someone has no phone, the match against the phone table will filter them out entirely.

Comment: Or a subquery in the `Where` clause to select the `people.id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After @Barmar pointed me in the right direction, I came up with this code:

```
SELECT
  id,
  name,
  group_concat(
    DISTINCT concat( number, ' (', phones.description, ')' )
    ORDER BY phones.description
    SEPARATOR '\n'
  ) AS phones,
  group_concat(
    DISTINCT concat( email, ' (', emails.description, ')' )
    ORDER BY emails.description
    SEPARATOR '\n'
  ) AS emails,
  group_concat(
    DISTINCT concat( address, ' (', addresses.description, ')' )
    ORDER BY addresses.description
    SEPARATOR '\n'
  ) AS addresses

FROM people
LEFT OUTER JOIN phones
  ON phones.person_id = id
LEFT OUTER JOIN emails
  ON emails.person_id = id
LEFT OUTER JOIN addresses
  ON addresses.person_id = id

WHERE id IN (
  SELECT DISTINCT person_id
  FROM phones
  WHERE number LIKE ?
  AND person_id IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT person_id
    FROM emails
    WHERE email LIKE ?
    AND person_id IN (
      SELECT DISTINCT person_id
      FROM addresses
      WHERE address LIKE ?
    )
  )
)
AND name LIKE ?
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY id DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid creating a cross product between all the child tables, do those searches in subqueries.

To get all the information from the child table related to the person, not just the matching rows, do a second join.

```
SELECT 
  people.id,
  name,
  group_concat(DISTINCT
    concat(number, ' (', p1.description, ')' )
    ORDER BY p1.description
    SEPARATOR '\n'
  ) AS phones,
  group_concat(DISTINCT
    concat(email, ' (', e1.description, ')' )
    ORDER BY e1.description
    SEPARATOR '\n'
  ) AS emails,
  group_concat(DISTINCT
    concat(address, ' (', a1.description, ')' )
    ORDER BY a1.description
    SEPARATOR '\n'
  ) AS addresses
FROM people
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
     SELECT DISTINCT person_id
     FROM phones
     WHERE number LIKE ?) AS phones
  ON phones.person_id = person.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN phones AS p1 ON p1.person_id = person.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
     SELECT DISTINCT person_id
     FROM emails
     WHERE email LIKE ?) AS emails
  ON emails.person_id = person.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN emails AS e1 ON e1.person_id = person.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
     SELECT DISTINCT person_id
     FROM addresses
     WHERE address LIKE ?) AS addresses
  ON addresses.person_id = person.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN addresses AS a1 ON a1.person_id = person.id
WHERE
  name LIKE ?
GROUP BY people.id
ORDER BY people.id DESC
```

Comment: Still getting lots of duplicated values, but thanks for pointing me in the right direction, I didn't know about subqueries, I'll learn about them and post my final code here once I get it to work properly.

Comment: Yeah, if different parameters match different people, it will indeed cause multiplication in `GROUP_CONCAT`. I added back `DISTINCT`.

Comment: ok after some more testing I see it's still not working x_x but you still have my upvote for pointing me to the right direction, I'm posting now the code I came up with which works well